# SQL Query - average data increase

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have data polling every x hours and it is based on a liquid level. The level always rises.

I need to know how to work out the average increase over a week (per day).

So if days data reads 1000-1200-1300-1400 then we know the average increase is 100 per day.

```
DateReceived  DeviceLevel Serial

1/mm/yyyy     3200         346
1/mm/yyyy     12000        222
2/mm/yyyy     3560         346
2/mm/yyyy     13600         222
```

Trying to use the

```
AVG()
```

function but to no evail.

Comment: Could you add some example data?

Comment: gave you a snippet of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self-join to find the level of the previous day.  That gives you the increase for a day.  An outer query could be used to find the average increase over a week:

```
select  datepart(wk, Day) as WeekNr
,       avg(IncreasePerDay) as AverageDailyIncrease
from    (
        select  cast(d1.MeasureDt as date) as Day
        ,       avg(d2.level) - avg(d1.level) as IncreasePerDay
        from    YourTable d1
        join    YourTable d2
        on      cast(d2.MeasureDt as date) = cast(d1.MeasureDt as date) + 1
        group by
                cast(d1.MeasureDt as date)
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        datepart(wk, Day)
```

Comment: `SELECT        DATEPART(wk, Day) AS WeekNr, AVG(IncreasePerDay) AS AverageDailyIncrease
FROM            (SELECT        CAST(d1.DateReceived AS date) AS Day, AVG(d2.DeviceLevel) - AVG(d1.DeviceLevel) AS IncreasePerDay
                          FROM            TBLReadings AS d1 INNER JOIN
                                                    TBLReadings AS d2 ON CAST(d2.DateReceived AS date) = CAST(d1.DateReceived AS date) + 1
       GROUP BY CAST(d1.DateReceived AS date)) AS SubQueryAlias
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, Day)` like this for my table? it errors "date is incompatible with int"

Answer (score 0):

For your table #t

```
select t2.serial, avg(t2.devicelevel-t1.devicelevel) from #t t1
    inner join #t t2 on t1.datereceived = dateadd(d,1,t2.datereceived)
group by t2.serial
```

For an interval of 4 hours...

```
create table #t (polldate datetime, amount int)
insert #t values ('2012-06-01 16:00', 200),
('2012-06-01 20:00', 220),
('2012-06-02 00:00', 250),
('2012-06-02 04:00', 270)

select avg(t1.amount-t2.amount) from #t t1
    inner join #t t2 on t1.polldate = dateadd(hh,4,t2.polldate)

drop table #t
```

Comment: does this code take yesterdays total and take away todays and leave the number that it has increased? @podiluska

Comment: It returns the average of the differences since the previous measurement.